# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when trying to change keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to remove some problematic `$oid` and everything that contains $ in a json file. I wrote:

```
import json
with open('C:\\Windows\\System32\\files\\news.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as handle:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in handle]
for k,v in data[0].items():
    #check if key has dict value
    if type(v) == dict:
        #find id with $
        r = list(data[k].keys())[0]
        #change value if $ occurs
        if r[0] == '$':
            data[k] = data[k][r]
print(data)
```

But I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. I know it is because the json dictionaries are made redeable for Python, but how do I fix it?

Edit: the .json file in my computer looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
  "$oid": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
  },
  "description": "some text",
  "startDate": {
  "$date": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
  },
  "completionDate": {
  "$date": "2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add the data format of the JSON file.

Comment: @pppig I did, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your k is a str and you try to call data[k]?
It will be better if you show the format of the json as well.

Updating with answer.

This should work for the given json. But if you want to for a larger file. looping can be tricky, specially because you're trying to modify the keys of a dictionary.

```
import json

line = '{"_id": { "$oid": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff" }, "description": "some text", "startDate": { "$date": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"},"completionDate": {"$date": "2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z"}}'

data = [json.loads(line)]
for k,v in data[0].items():
    if type(v) == dict:
        for k2, v2 in data[0][k].items():
            if k2[0] == '$':
                formatted = k2[1:]
                del data[0][k][k2]
                data[0][k][formatted] = v2
print(data)
```

Comment: I did, thank you. It is just a small example and now I am not even sure it removes all the $ in the file.

Comment: This should be a comment and not answer.

Comment: Sorry, will use comments next time.

Comment: @n.mathfreak maybe I misunderstood your requirement. Maybe you want to remove the whole entry, and not modify keys. But I hope since the above code fixes the key issue, it should be okay.

Comment: Again thank you for editing, but now the error is that on line 8 the dictionary keys changed during the iteration. I think there might be just a typo and I'm trying to figure it out. Indeed, a ".copy()" was missing after the dictionary. But it just removes the $, it doesn't change the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# import json

# with open('C:\\Windows\\System32\\files\\news.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as handle:
#     data = [json.loads(line) for line in handle]

data = [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
        },
        "description": "some text",
        "startDate": {
            "$date": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
        },
        "completionDate": {
            "$date": "2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z"
        }
    }
]

for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        # check if key has dict value
        del_keys = set()
        if type(v) == dict:
            # find id with $
            del_keys.update([i for i in v if i.startswith("$")])
        [v.pop(key) for key in del_keys]
print(data)

# [{'_id': {}, 'description': 'some text', 'startDate': {}, 'completionDate': {}}]
```